# Check list of values is NULL in PL/SQL

Tags: java, sql, plsql

Is there a way to check is a list of values is `NULL` in PL/SQL?

I have something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE t.dataId IN (:myList) OR :myList IS NULL
```

At run-time, the `:myList` symbol is substituted for a list of strings e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE t.dataId IN ('a', 'b', 'c') OR  ('a', 'b', 'c') IS NULL
```

I've realised that `('a', 'b', 'c') IS NULL` is invalid PL/SQL, so I wondered if there is another way to check a list of values evaluate to `NULL`.

The behaviour I'm attempting to emulate would evaluate `('a', 'b', 'c')` to `NOT NULL`. I'm trying to avoid creating another variable (e.g. :myListFlag) which would return `''` if the list was empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe `COALESCE` will help you:

It evaluates a list of values left to right and returns the first value that is `NOT NULL`. If all values are `NULL`, it evaluates to `NULL`, which is a single value that you can check for `IS NULL`.

```
 SELECT * FROM myTable t WHERE t.dataId IN (:myList) OR COALESCE(:myList) IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this function may be the solution. I've realised that if :myList is empty it returns `''` so I think the solution would be to use `COALESCE(:myList, '') IS NULL`. Does that look right?

Comment: @Alex: I do not have a Oracle DB at hand to test that. Please report if it works.

Comment: I used the form COALESCE(:myList, NULL) IS NULL but COALESCE(:myList, '') IS NULL would also work since Oracle treats '' as NULL as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/15357813/908677 or http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Oracle-treats-empty-strings-as-NULL

Comment: COALESCE(:myList) still works, it just expects comma separated values. It might give you a lint error, but when you run the code, it goes through because :myList will actually be a list or null.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the following syntax doing what you expect:

```
WHERE t.dataId IN (:myList)
```

In general, variable substitution results in a single value.  So, if the value is `'a,b,c'`, then this will match a value of `'a,b,c'`, but not `'a'`.

You can do this with other expressions.  The most general (i.e. works in  most databases) is something like:

```
where ','||:myList||',' like '%,'||t.data_id||',%'
```

With such a structure, you can readily say:

```
where ','||:myList||',' like '%,'||t.data_id||',%' and :myList is not null
```

There are definitely other ways of doing this.  A quick search on the web comes up with things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800180/pl-sql-comma-seperated-list-within-in-clause).

Comment: I'm using the Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate class, an example is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433438/how-to-use-a-list-of-string-in-namedparameterjdbctemplate-to-get-results

Comment: @Alex . . . That's cool.  I'm glad this functionality is starting to be supported.  My recommendation would be to convert the list to a string and pass that as another parameter which you can compare to `NULL` (or `''`).