# How to use REGEXP_SUBSTR to filter?

Tags: oracle

I have a select query which is working in postgres , but not in Oracle

The Select Query Uses regexp_split_to_array  , which is not suppourted in Oracle

The regexp_split_to_array  used here is to   filter non working days

```
select 
  * 
from 
  department 
where 
  dept_status = 'A' 
  AND NOT (
    #{DAY} = any ( regexp_split_to_array(lower(non_working_days), ',')))
  AND dept_loc = 'US'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbac4/4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PL/SQL - comma separated list within IN CLAUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800180/pl-sql-comma-separated-list-within-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have a function `regexp_split_to_array` . Instead you can use `LIKE` (which is much faster than regular expressions) to check for a sub-string match (including the surrounding delimiters so you match a complete term):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   department 
WHERE  dept_status = 'A' 
AND    ',' || lower(non_working_days) || ',' NOT LIKE '%,' || :DAY || ',%'
AND    dept_loc = 'US'
```

*Note: You should pass in variables using bind variables such as `:day` or `?` (for an anonymous bind variable) rather than relying on a pre-processor to replace strings as it will help to prevent SQL injection attacks.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jN_EFKd0)

Comment: I should pass the bind variablr as day

Comment: Thank u so much, can't we do the same using reg sub str of oracle?

Comment: @gooddog I have not idea what you are using (i.e. Java, C#, PHP, etc.) to pass the bind variable; without knowing that it is impossible to contemplate how you would pass it.

Comment: Yes, you could write an expression using regular expressions to split the string and then match individual terms; but why would you want to when looking for matching sub-strings is much more efficient? (And would probably also be more efficient in PostgreSQL)

Comment: I am using java to pass the bind variable, which is working in postgres

Comment: @gooddog Java supports named and anonymous bind variables with Oracle as well as with PostgreSQL; use whichever type of bind variable you prefer.